# XMPP muc room left once user offline iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xmpp, openfire

I am creating room with Xmmp open fire ,first  time its working fine
and  if group admin go to offline then all member left room  ,when 
come to online  not  join the room . how to rejoin  the room ? !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how XMPP Multi-User Chat works. Multi-User Chat specification is presence-based. When you are offline, you are not an occupant of the room.

Comment: how to re-join my existing members into a group?

Comment: XEP-0045 (MUC) is based on presence. Uses MucSub, if you want to use an extension of MUC that is not based on presence: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/extensions/muc-sub/

Answer (score 0):

After creating room set your XMPP Room persistent using below code...

```
-(void)xmppRoomDidJoin:(XMPPRoom *)sender {
    NSLog("I did join.");
    [sender fetchConfigurationForm];
}

-(void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchConfigurationForm:(NSXMLElement *)configForm {

    NSXMLElement *newConfig = [configForm copy];

    NSArray *fields = [newConfig elementsForName:@"field"];

    for (NSXMLElement *field in fields) {

         NSString *var = [field attributeStringValueForName:@"var"];
         // Make Room Persistent

        if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_persistentroom"]) {

        [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
        [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];

        }
   }

   [sender configureRoomUsingOptions:newConfig];

}
```

that time if room owner is offline that time XMPP Room is exist with all member

Comment: I did the same thing as you mentioned, but still I am not receiving groups. I am sending invitation to friend. friend either accept the group invitation or not, this will not return any groups list. Do you have any idea about this? I am using ejabberd.